# DownloadError: ApplicationError

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a function called DownloadData() which uses `url.fetch()`. 
From time to time it throws `DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2 timed out error`.

How can I catch this error?
With `except DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2 timed` or only `DownloadError`?
It is hard to reproduce this error so I can not know which except to use.

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 1):

Just "except DownloadError:" should work fine. Your second example isn't valid Python, though.